# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, reverse

```
import java.util.*;

class Firstjava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String to reverse");
        char n = sc.next();
        char[] arr = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.next();
        }
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be time well spent to read about data types, specifically about strings and characters. They are not the same thing, and it's important to understand why.

Comment: Here is a good start: [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) in The Java Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

The next() function returns a String. Therefore you cannot cast it to character as you have done in

```
char n = sc.next();
```

Instead, you can directly take a String as input.
and then print the characters from the end as you have done in the last for loop. Thus you don't need the character array that you have .
I have commented out the code that is not required

```
class Firstjava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String to reverse");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        // char[] arr = new char[s.length()];
        // for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // arr[i] = s.charAt(i);
        // }d
        System.out.println("reversed string is ");
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(" " + s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```